# Is the "The case of the 500-mile email" True?

Tags: email

http://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail

Could It be true? Or it's just a joke? :O

Comment: Good story, I'd never heard that one before.  It's off topic, however, so this will likely get closed.

Comment: Can you point out the exact FAQ point that states that this is off-topic? who gived -1? why?

Comment: from the FAQ: You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Answer (score 7):

I remember reading this quite a long time ago. Nobody ever really had any reason to doubt the credibility of the author. Remember, the Internet was a slightly saner place then. What's more, is this same question is addressed in the FAQ (linked from the original story).

> **Did this actually happen, or were you
> just spinning a yarn?**
>
> Yes, it
> happened. At the time, I was running
> the centralized campus email system,
> Isis, at the University of North
> Carolina at Chapel Hill. I was
> informally responsible for some
> aspects of the email systems in
> departments who chose to run their own
> independent systems. Most notably for
> the purposes of this story, I wrote
> sendmail.cf (Sendmail configuration)
> files that were used in most of the
> mail servers on the campus.

http://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail-faq.html